# Override universal background image from external CSS stylesheet at one page in Stylus extension

Tags: html, css, firefox-addon, stylus

Sorry about possible unclear title and my weak skills of the English language. I use Stylus extension at Firefox. I want to redesign one webpage from website [*Jyväskylä yliopisto Moodle*](https://moodle.jyu.fi/) but I need some help.

Background image comes from external CSS stylesheet and I want to override background at one single page. I want to use white colour as background instead of background image. How can I change background? Technically this should be easy but this CSS stylesheet is very unclear and too complicated for me.

CSS stylesheet can be found [here](https://moodle.jyu.fi/theme/styles.php/maisteriboost/1566995634_1559738305/all).

Universal background is [/theme/image.php/maisteriboost/theme/1566995618/dashboard_bg](https://moodle.jyu.fi/theme/image.php/maisteriboost/theme/1566995618/dashboard_bg)

---

It might be something like this:

```css
SOMETHING {
    background-color: white !important); 
}
```

But what is that SOMETHING? I tried this:

```css
#dash-page-bg {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

And also this:

```css
.popover-region-toggle::before#dash-page-bg {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```

But neither of these worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding an inline style for the background. `style="background: white"`
My guess is maybe the universal background is loading after your styles and it could be causing it to override.